# Как регуляркой заменить у картинок атрибут src на data-src внутри блока с определенным ID?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пример странички:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div class="detailimage">
                <a href="/upload/111.jpg" class="fancybox" title="для морских судов">
                    <img src="/iblock/1111.jpg" class="img-responsive" title="для морских судов" alt="для морских" itemprop="image">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <link rel="image_src" href="/iblock/555.jpg"  />
                <img style="" align="right" src="/upload/222.jpg"  alt="" title="" align="middle"/>
                <p>
                    <img src="/upload/333.jpg" style="padding-left:35px; padding-right:25px;" alt="" title="" align="right">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <img style="padding-left:35px; padding-right:25px; padding-top:15px"  src="/upload/444.jpg" alt="" title="" />
            </div>
            <img style="padding-top:15px" data-src="/upload/777.jpg" alt="" title="">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Подобрал регулярку для замены атрибута src на data-src, спасибо Mike:

```
preg_replace('~<img[^>]*\K(?=src)~i','data-',$string)
```

Но как это же самое сделать только для тех картинок, которые внутри блока с ID=content ?

Comment: выучить регулярные выражения?

Comment: Сдаётся мне, что на php не получится... По крайней мере, даже при условии, что в этом div'е нет вложенных div'ов, мне нужен предпросмотр назад с произвольной длиной.

Comment: Не используйте регулярки, воспользуйтесь `DOMDocument` для того, чтобы найти и заменить искомые значения.

Comment: Если хотите сделать велосипед, то вот вам [пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d097b818a016f38a31844ffd02d99a2ddf3d2e1)

Answer (score 2):

Можно сперва находить необходимый блок с атрибутом, а потом производить в нём замену:

```
$str = ''; // html-код

$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '~<div id="content">.+?</div>~s',
    function($m){
        return preg_replace('~<img[^>]*\K(?=src)~', 'data-', $m[0]);
    },
    $str
);

echo $str;
```

Comment: Хм, работает. Интересно, в чем подводный камень? В скорости?